# What is PCAmixdata's recodqual() doing, and what is its failure condition?

Tags: r, recode

I'm trying to debug a call to [`kmeansvar`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClustOfVar/ClustOfVar.pdf) in some data I'm working on, but before I can even try to reproduce the issue, I have to figure out what this error message from [recodqual()](https://github.com/cran/ClustOfVar/blob/master/R/recodqual.R) is saying:

> Error in recodqual(X.quali) : There are columns in X.quali where all
>   the categories are identical

The source is fairly short, but without comments, and I don't understand the test condition or the error message:

```
recodqual <-
function(X)
    {
        X <- as.matrix(X)
        GNA <- tab.disjonctif.NA(X)
        G <- replace(GNA,is.na(GNA),0)
        ns <- apply(G,2,sum)
        nmiss <- apply((apply(GNA,2,is.na)),2,sum)
        n <- nrow(X)
        if(sum((n-nmiss)==ns)!=0) stop("There are columns in X.quali where all the categories are identical")
        return(G)   
}
```

What is the `stop` message trying to say, and what is it testing?

- I thought it was failing because of identical columns, but I got this error with a data.table of only two different categorical variables.
- If made sure I had a data.table with two different categorical variables with more than one unique value per column, the call succeeded.
- However, filtering the categorical subset by uniqueness in rows resulted in the call failing as above:

  ```
  cat.cols <- Filter(function(col) { 
    !is.numeric(main.data[,get(col)]) &
      length(main.data[,unique(get(col))]) > 1
  }, colnames(main.data))
  # followed by call using main.data[,cat.cols,with=FALSE]
  ```

I'll add some test data to reproduce shortly.

Comment: What packages are you using? `tab.disjonctif.NA` is not a base `R` function, at least that I can find.  Without knowing what that function does, it is really hard to debug this.  Based on the output message though, I would guess the error occurs when all the values in a column are identical.

Comment: This is from PCAmixdata.